# ASP.net page with webmethod loading into Coldfusion page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod, jquery-load

Hey all I have a unique issue when I try loading my **asp.net** page into an **Coldfusion** page via **jquery .load()**.

I know the issue. When calling the webmethod **(via AJAX POST)** on my asp.net page, its taking the path of the **Coldfusion** page url:

```
<b> Requested URL: </b>/production/Default.aspx/getChartDetails<br><br>
```

The **asp.net** page is originally located in:

```
http://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/dotnet/productionTimeline/Default.aspx.
```

and the **Coldfusion** page is located on:

```
https://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/production/htmlpage.html
```

So going back to the first statement above - Its placing **production** in the URL link to the **webmethod** which causes the 404.

```
/production/Default.aspx/getChartDetails
```

How can I get it to load up normally (**Default.aspx/getChartDetails**) instead of using the current URL path on the **Coldfusion** page?

Comment: place your HTML file inside your ASP.Net web app and access this from the site (then you don't need absolute path)

Comment: @techspider Cant. It has to be an HTML page.

Comment: are they both on the same domain? are they both on the same IIS Web site?

Comment: @techspider yes, that is correct.

Comment: they, why do you need absolute path? why can't you use relative path to your ASPX page from your HTML?

Comment: It's a **Coldfusion** page.

Comment: something like `~/dotnet/productionTimeline/Default.aspx/getChartDetails`

Comment: @techspider Doing that just produces **/production/~/dotnet/productionTimeline/Default.aspx/getChartDetails**